# How to fix Google search SEO after transfer old website and hosting to new framework website and hosting?

Tags: search, seo, transfer

I had an ecommerce website with magento and Nexcess hosting, but now i have changed the website to new framework Kohana and Arxive hosting. Website has SAME DOMAIN NAME. I have moved my website to new framework and hosting for about a month, but Google still cache old information SEO from my old website even though it still caches few of information of the new website. I tried to search my website through Google, but there is few errors happening when i clicked the links from Google that cause users could not view my website or products.

For example: https://www.website.com -> Google said shop away, but my shop is still available with new framework.

Another example: search product name: zippo lighter.... -> click on it --> links error with new Kohana framework message (BUT if i view product from my website.com, that product is display well; there is no message)

FYI: My new website has SEO functions very well, there are tittle, meta keywork, meta description...
So how do i clear or delete caches from old website (i already deleted website from old hositng)? or what can i do to make my website work well with Google after transfer?

Thank you so much

Comment: If you have changed urls, then you need to redirect by 301 redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Google has not reprocessed your website completely and is confused. You can create a `sitemap.xml` with all the URLs of your website and a recent `lastmod` date. Then submit it into Google Webmaster Tools and let crawlers revisit your site. May sure you don't block those links with your `robots.txt`.

Remember that Google Cache lags behind the index. It is often out of sync and cannot be used as reliable information about indexed content.

If your issue persist, report it to Google's Webmaster Forum.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. With your mention, there are no sitemap.xml and robots.txt on my current kohana website. So i would think this might be the cause of the problem that i mention above. So can you guide me or share me some links how to create a sitemap.xml and robots.txt for my website? thanks

Comment: Yes: https://seosummaries.com/expertise/robots-txt-implementation-seo.html and https://seosummaries.com/expertise/sitemap-implementation-seo.html